# Do you know why i am getting this problem

Tags: html, css, web, css-position, z-index

I am facing a problem in z-index where I create empty div and set all its properties as below but still, this isn't working with boxes it's not going behind the boxes

```css
// Boxes
.boxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 70px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  margin: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

.box {
  width: 74.5%;
  height: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  border-radius: 11px;
}

.box h1 {
  font-size: 37px;
  padding-top: 3.2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.box p {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.black-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: black;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Gyms</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, eveniet.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Classes</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, eveniet.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <h1>Activities</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, eveniet.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="black-back"></div>
```

I want it to be like that as shown in this image

[Refrence Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUTfm.png)

Here is a link to my website you can check where I want it to place this black rectangle

https://www.fitardo.com/

Comment: What kind of styles do your other elements have?  Please post a minimal verifiable example.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post your html code man..

Comment: Sorry for that it's my first time doing this I don't know how to ask question by the way i have posted HTML code you can see that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. Actually you have not assigned any background (color or image) to the ".box" class that is why it is showing like this due to transparency. Just add "background: #fff;" in ".box" class. I have given below updated class code for the same. Try this, it will work:

```
.box{
    width: 74.5%;
    height: 250px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem 3rem;
    border-radius: 11px;
    background:#fff;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**you need to use margin-top: -100px;**

```
.black-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: I want to take the [div black-back] almost back to the box like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUTfm.png